# Musical references in JoJo's Bizarre Adventure

Tags: reference, jojos-bizarre-adventure

I was recently introduced to [JoJo's Bizarre Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JoJo%27s_Bizarre_Adventure_(2012_TV_series)) and noticed several musical references that seemed out of place for the setting of the first "part" Phantom Blood.

- One of the supporting characters is named Robert E. Speedwagon (oddly similar to REO Speedwagon)
- An antagonist, Dio shares the name of a heavy metal superstar Ronnie James Dio
- One of the mentors to the warriors is Master Tompeti (no heartbreakers)
- The closing theme is from 1972 Yes! Turnabout

I'm sure there are many other references that I have not seen yet (please be mindful of spoilers).

Is there any in-universe reason for these names or are these somewhat random Easter Eggs (perhaps to introduce great music to a younger generation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is just an example of Theme Naming - characters in a work of fiction being named according to a theme. It's quite common - *Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha*, for example, has characters mostly named after cars, while *RWBY* has characters mostly named after colours. In the case of *JoJo*, as you've observed, it has very many characters named after musicians, including all the ones you've spotted in Part 1 - without giving anything away, it gets a *lot* more obvious from Part 3 onwards.

(Incidentally, there is in fact a pop star named [JoJo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JoJo_(singer)), but there's no connection between her and JJBA, which began publication before she was born.)

Comment: +1 I accepted your answer as it gave me an insight into the nomenclature of other anime series, which I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an Easter eggs. It's just  Hirohiko Araki named characters after things that inspired him. 
[List of references in JoJo](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_cultural_references_in_JoJo%27s_Bizarre_Adventure)

Comment: +1, thank you for the awesome link.  I read a few, but stopped before part 3 that @F1Krazy refers to.  I haven't watched those episodes yet